# .NET Generate Sequence Diagrams From Running Code

Tags: .net, sequence-diagram, auto-generate

Is there a tool that can generate sequence diagrams from running .NET code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) will generate sequence diagrams from running code. You set break points where you want your diagramming to begin and end and then run the code and it will give you a sequence diagram of the code that ran. I have done this successfully with C# code.

[Here are the instructions from the user guide.](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/visual_execution_analyzer/generating_sequence_diagrams.html)

Comment: this sounds like a solid albeit expensive tool

Comment: I have found it useful. Both of my last two clients have purchased it so I've never had to pay for it.

Comment: @JimAnderson : The instructions link is dead

Answer (score 3):

Enterprise Architect made by Sparx Systems works well for generating sequence diagrams from code. It basically records (based on your start/end points) the runtime and spits out a sequence diagram. They even have a video demo of it somewhere on their site. I think EA is between $200-$300 bucks, but a great tool non the less.

[This video demo shows how to setup source/debugging in EA and at the end you see how to generate a sequence diagram.](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/ASP_Net/ASP_NET.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I researched this a while ago myself and [I think SDE does what you need](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/vs/demos/umlsupport/sequence.jsp) I think (I was unable to convince management to follow through on the research, but the demo looks good)

Edit: oh and try [visual uml](http://www.visualobject.com/default.htm) too.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean? Determine from the runtime execution path the sequence diagram? I do not believe it possible.

If you mean to **create** sequence diagram from code and data then the [GoDiagram tool from Northwoods](http://www.nwoods.com/) can create really complex diagrams and I believe sequence diagram are certainly doable. And, BTW, collecting the proper diagnostic data you can also solve the first problem...

Comment: Enterprise Architect will do this from a debugging session.