Strategies for Maintaining Complex Mediator/CQRS Data Flows in .NET
I'm working on a .NET project using Mediator and the CQRS pattern. As the complexity of my application grows, I'm facing challenges in managing complex data flows that involve numerous handlers from initial request to final response.
Specifically, I'm struggling with:

Maintaining a Clear Overview: It's becoming difficult to visualize and track the entire flow of data from the initial request to the final response. I'm worried about missing steps or introducing redundant logic.
Avoiding Duplicate Implementations: I'm concerned about accidentally creating multiple handlers or queries that perform similar operations, leading to code duplication and potential inconsistencies.

I'm looking for guidance on best practices and strategies to address these issues.
Key Questions:

How do experienced developers effectively diagram or document complex Mediator/CQRS data flows?
What techniques can help me ensure that handlers remain focused and don't overlap in functionality?
Are there tools or libraries that can assist in visualizing or analyzing these flows within a .NET project?

Additional Details:

I'm using MediatR library for .NET
The complexity primarily arises from multiple layers of handlers and queries that interact with each other and the database

Any insights, tips, or recommended approaches would be greatly appreciated

The most common way to document a complex flow is through a sequence diagram.  There are tools to help you generate them, and even some that will generate them from running code.
As far as avoiding duplication, it's probably going to come down to naming things intuitively, and decomposing your mediators into smaller pieces that can be assembled.
It is one of the real concerns with the mediator pattern is that it can easily become a god object with all the logic tied up in one object, you will have to be disciplined in the decomposition of that object into smaller domain-specific objects that can be maintained with some degree of sanity.
The whole point in the mediator pattern is to decouple code from each other.  Decoupled code structurally often lacks cohesion, and it is up to you to make sure it still makes sense so that you can manage it.  If it is becoming too complicated, consider coarser-grained components that are easier to conceptually manage.

Sequence diagrams are definitely a helpful way to visualize complex data flows. However, manually maintaining them can be a challenge and requires a lot of discipline to keep them up-to-date.
I'm wondering if there are any good tools out there that can automatically generate these diagrams from the codebase. I've explored Visual Studio's Code Map, but it doesn't capture the entire flow, as it only shows one link in the chain at a time.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388738/net-generate-sequence-diagrams-from-running-code has some useful advice.   I've used AOP to build my own in the past.  These days opentelemetry or System.Trace could give you this without having to dive too deep into the CLR.

Enterprise Architect looks promesing, however, setting start and end breakpoints for each sequence in our extensive data flows seems like it would be an incredibly time-consuming and tedious process. Especially if code changes over time.

Welcome to the pain and suffering required to maintain enterprise architecture documentation.   It's hard, and sometimes not worth the effort.   The optimal amount of documentation to maintain is very situational, and unfortunately requires real judgement to decide what's worth creating/keeping/updating, and what is more work than it's worth.  The "right" amount is "just enough" so that you can figure out/remember what's going on.
